# Android textedit that behaves like the gmail app "To" field

Tags: android, email

I need to allow my users to enter multiple email addresses into a textedit and I would like to have the ability to suggest contacts as they type the address and once they enter in one or more emails I would like to validate the email and visually signify that the emails are added.  The gmail app does a great job of this.  Below are pictures of what I'm talking about.  Can anyone give me some suggestions or point me in the right direction?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have some issue. Please hv a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676347/setting-multiple-custom-elements-to-multiautocompletetextview-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: No I haven't, and that is exactly what i'm looking for.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have some issue. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676347/setting-multiple-custom-elements-to-multiautocompletetextview-android